# Partition function with itertools

Tags: python

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def partition(n, iterable):
   p = izip_longest(*([iter(iterable)] * n))
   r = []
   for x in p:
       s = set(x)
       s.discard(None)
       r.append(list(s))
   return r

print partition(2, range(100))
```

I saw it from a recruit and the company said there were potential problems, but I can't find out anything wrong with my test case:

```
print partition(2, range(100))
print partition(1, range(100))
print partition(-1, range(100))
print partition(101, range(100))
```

Comment: Does your code work as intended?

Comment: An obvious problem is that you have no way of distinguishing the iterator stopping, from a `None` value that's actually a legit part of the sequence.

Comment: Is this your code or a recruit's code? Posts on Code Review must be *your* code, not someone else's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elephants in the room:

- Single letter variable names are to be avoided. Each variable should have a suggestive meaningful name.
- They probably expected you to write automated tests, just printing a result for visual inspection is not a real way of testing. `assert` is easy to use and can get you started on automated testing.